# as.POSXct returning NA

Tags: r, posixct

I'm trying to convert a string to a POSIXct object, but if I do this

```
x <- as.POSIXct('15/10/17', tz = 'America/Sao_Paulo', format = '%d/%m/%y')
```

the output is NA. I think that it occurs because it became  daylight saving time in São Paulo on day 15/10/17, so midnight of that day doesn't exist. One solution is to force x to be another value in that day like

```
x <- structure(1508036400, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "America/Sao_Paulo")
```

But I was wodering if there is a more elegant solution.

My session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252        LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.2 tools_3.4.2    yaml_2.1.14    fortunes_1.5-4
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if this is a bug in `as.POSIXct()` or if it is saving you from an obscure data problem.

In either case, if you only have date information, then it is best practice to store your data as a `Date` rather than `POSIXct`.

Try `as.Date('15/10/17', format = '%d/%m/%y')`.